# Accessing S3 on AWS EMR when running application within Docker container via spark-submit

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I'm running an application that accesses data in an AWS S3 folder. The following script `spark_emr_s3_test.py` serves as a simple proxy for my application that reproduces my error:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sess = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = sess.read.csv('s3://path/to/my/dataset/folder')
print("Number of items: %d" % (df.count()))
```

Simple enough, and it doesn't fail when I run the following command...

```
spark-submit spark_emr_s3_test.py
```

... on an EMR cluster.

When I, however, try running the same application within a Docker container as described [here in the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/run-spark-applications-with-docker-using-amazon-emr-6-0-0-beta/), I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.csv. : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
```

The exact command I use is the one in the above documentation link, but with values relevant to my case:

```
$ DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME=123456789123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/emr-docker-examples:pyspark-example
$ DOCKER_CLIENT_CONFIG=hdfs:///user/hadoop/config.json
$ spark-submit --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.executorEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_TYPE=docker \
    --conf spark.executorEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_IMAGE=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME \
    --conf spark.executorEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_CLIENT_CONFIG=$DOCKER_CLIENT_CONFIG \
    --conf spark.executorEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_MOUNTS=/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_TYPE=docker \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_IMAGE=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_CLIENT_CONFIG=$DOCKER_CLIENT_CONFIG \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_MOUNTS=/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro \
    --num-executors 2 \
    spark_emr_s3_test.py
```

I can confirm that the error has nothing to do with any configuration or access management matter, as my script runs and the error pops up at the call to the CSV read function.

It appears to me that I can solve this by resolving the EMRFS dependencies within the container, or directly via `spark-submit` but I haven't been able to figure out how, and what exactly these dependencies are.

Comment: `/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*` add this to ur class path. This location contains `hadoop-assembly.jar` which contains `EmrFileSystem.class`. Better option would be create a sylink inside HADOOP_HOME dir.

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you suggested by appending `--conf driver.extraClassPath=/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/* --conf executor.extraClassPath=/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*` to the above `spark-submit` command. That didn't work, so then I tried passing the JAR specifically by appending `--jars /usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.34.0.jar` . That error disappeared, but I have another one now. In any case, I wanted to check with you whether you might suggest doing what I did by using `--conf ...` in some other way.

Comment: Looks like the other error I ran into isn't related to this one, or your solution. If you post your suggestion as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @user1953384: I am also facing the same issue, and there seems to be not much help on this. Could you please post your solution as an answer on how to include EMRFS in the docker container, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is as far as I got before shelving it and deciding to do something else. It may have been fixed, but I no longer work there.